# How do I manipulate the output produced by the plain bibliography style?

Tags: bibliographies

I have the following output in the references: X. Mao J. Appleby and A. Rodkina. On stochastic stabilization of difference equations. Discrete and Continuous Dynamical Systems, 15:843–857, 2006. How can I put a comma between the first two authors, delete the colon that comes after the volume and also put the year before the pages. That is I need the output: X. Mao, J. Appleby and A. Rodkina. On stochastic stabilization of difference equations. Discrete and Continuous Dynamical Systems, 15, (2006), 843–857. I am using `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and in the bibtex file I have

```
@article{Rod1,
     author   ="J.~Appleby, X.~Mao and A.~Rodkina",
     title    ="On Stochastic Stabilization Of Difference Equations",
     journal  ="Discrete and Continuous Dynamical Systems",
     volume   ="15",
     pages    ="843--857",
     year     ="2006" }
```

Comment: `author="J. Appleby and X. Mao and A. Rodkina",`

Comment: @egreg Thanks that fixes the comma between the first two authors.

Comment: @egreg Are you going to provide an answer to the other parts of the question?

Comment: That requires changing the bibliography style.

Comment: @egreg I have looked at the various styles available at [biblio styles](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.pdf) but they do not match exactly what I need.

Comment: Did you try amsplain?

Comment: I tried that but whenever an author has more than one item a dash is used instead of the authors' names. Thanks I will use one in the suggested listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to BibTeX rules, your paper has *two* authors; the first one has family name "J.~Appleby" and given name "X.~Mao".

Don't use ties in the `.bib` file and separate author with the keyword `and`:

```
@article{Rod1,
     author  = {J. Appleby and X. Mao and A. Rodkina},
     title   = {On Stochastic Stabilization Of Difference Equations},
     journal = {Discrete and Continuous Dynamical Systems},
     volume  = {15},
     pages   = {843--857},
     year    = {2006},
}
```

An equivalent (in this case) input would be

```
     author  = {Appleby, J. and Mao, X. and Rodkina, A.},
```

Braces instead of quotes are a personal preference of mine; the trailing comma is very useful in case you add some new field.